# Puzzle to determine weights of coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve an interesting puzzle that has the following constraints-

There exists a black box that takes a set of values of the variables, plugs them into an unknown equation (but with a fixed number of variables) and returns the output.

We know that the equation is of the form:
$c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 \ldots c_Nx_N$

And the sum of all the positive coefficients adds up to $1$, and the sum of all the negative coefficients adds up to $-1$.

I want to minimize the number of calls made to the black box while still estimating the coefficients that are positive and those that are negative.

We know that it is an underdetermined system of equations. We can pass any set of the variables to the black box and get the decimal result.

The variables can only take a value between $0$ and $1$. Hence the result of the black box can only be between $-1$ and $1$.

The minimizing constraint is the number of calls to the black box. Is there an efficient way or a known problem that I'm unaware of?

Comment: "I want to minimize the number of calls made to the black box while still estimating the coefficients that are positive and those that are negative." I don't understand what you intend here.

Comment: I want to understand how I can estimate the SIGN of all the coefficients while making the least amount of calls to the blackbox. The naive way to solve it would be to make N calls to the black box, and the value returned would be the coefficient for each variable from 1 to N.
However, I don't need to know the exact coefficient. I want to know if there's a way to, with fewer than N calls to the black box, determine the SIGN of the coefficient for each variable. That would allow me to complete an optimal solution to the puzzle.

Comment: The coefficients can be zero? They are in $\mathbb{Z} $ or in $\mathbb{R}$? Do you know the bound of them, for example $l \le c_i \le u$, or at least the bound of negative (or positive) coefficients?

Comment: You call the result "integer", but also say that it must be between $-1$ and $1$. Does this means you only get $-1, 0, 1$ as output? If so, is it rounding, or what? Or were you mistaken in calling the result "integer".

Comment: @PaulSinclair I was mistaken in calling it an integer, it's a decimal between -1 and 1.

Comment: @NN2 The coefficients cannot be 0, they have to be either negative or positive. They are in ℤ and they lie between -1 and 1. The sum of all negative coefficients is -1 and the sum of all positive coefficients is 1.

Comment: @AshayChangwani Are you sure? It's impossible that "the sum of all negative coefficients is -1 " while these coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$. From that, we can deduce that there is only 1 coefficent that is equal to $-1$.
$$$$
For your information, a number in $\mathbb{Z}$ if it is for example! -2, -3, 1, 2 ,3,... and a number in $\mathbb{R}$ if it is 1.02  ;   3.07,   -2.45,....

Comment: You are seeking $N$ bits of information. Because you know two facts - the sum of the positive and of the negative coefficients, that should be enough to supply at least two bits. Which leaves $N-2$ bits to be determined by submitting values and examining the results. I'm not sure it is possible to get more than one bit from a single experiment. If we had some additional knowledge about the coefficients, it might be possible to design experiments that give more than one useful bit of information from the result, but I don't see how as is. It may be that using $N-2$ experiments may be required.

Comment: @AshayChangwani If we know that the coefficients are rational (ref :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number )  and there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that all $|c_i|>\epsilon$ for $i=1,...,n$, then it suffices $\color{red}{1}$ calls for determining all values of $c_i$ (not only their signs, but also their values)